# Add a Column to a Array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Hey Guys I have a Array with some Colums already inside. I add the rows with a Foreach loop with Get-Childitem. Now I need to put a command insde there so that I can get a other Row with the name that I already have in a other Variable added.

```
$Gesamt = foreach ($Names in $Pfad){
$Gesamt = $Pfad.name
Get-ChildItem -Path \\Server\users\z01\$($names)\*.pst , \\eServer\users\z01\$($names)\Archiv\*.pst , \\Server\users\z01\$($names)\Outlook\*.pst   | measure Length -sum

}
```

The Names are in `$Pfad.names$` But it doesn't work that way...

`$Pfad` is created like that

```
$Pfad = Get-ChildItem \\Server\users\z01
```

Comment: Please show how you create/populate `$Pfad` in the first place

Comment: I've edited the Question. Its written now at the bottom. In z01 are the Usernames with ther directory inside.

Comment: [1] use `Select-Object` to build a new object with the props that you want. ///// [2] what version of PoSh do you need to work with? you have both v2 & v3 listed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select-Object` to create new objects with multiple properties (or "columns" if you will) based on existing objects:

```
$Gesamt = Get-ChildItem \\Server\users\z01 |Select-Object Name,@{Name='TotalSize';Expression={ (Get-ChildItem -Path \\Server\users\z01\$($_.Name)\*.pst , \\eServer\users\z01\$($_.Name)\Archiv\*.pst , \\Server\users\z01\$($_.Name)\Outlook\*.pst   | Measure Length -Sum).Sum }}
```